# How can I add an integrated Google search to my website?

Tags: search, google-custom-search

Basically I have a website.  I have a properly setup sitemap so I assume Google knows about all of my pages.  And I've seen on some sites, the search form leads to a page with the shell of the original site but the results are clearly provided by Google.  Similar to codinghorror.com's search, however his results aren't shown within his website's layout.

Any idea what I'm talking about or how to achieve this?

Comment: HERE, IT IS VERY SIMPLE: https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/how-can-i-integrate-google-search-box-to-my-website-by-implementing-custom-code.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://cse.google.com/cse/

^ Perhaps you're looking for Google Custom Search Engine

Answer (score 14):

Nov. 2008: Like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20081231030633/http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_can_i_add_a_google_search_box_to_my_web_site.html) (but you will find a more [up-to-date 2012 example here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13822927/6309))

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">

<div style="border:1px solid black;padding:4px;width:20em;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td>
<input type="text"   name="q" size="25"
 maxlength="255" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Google Search" /></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" style="font-size:75%">
<input type="checkbox"  name="sitesearch"
 value="askdavetaylor.com" checked /> only search Ask Dave Taylor<br />
</td></tr></table>
</div>

</form>
```

For displaying the results in a separate frame, you have [this site](http://www.cfhunt.com/) as an example.

That would be something along the lines of:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showFrame () {
        var e = document.getElementById("if1");
        e.style.visibility = "visible" ;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p> </p>
    <p>
    <span id="spSearch" onclick="showFrame()">Search</span>
    </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p><iframe name="I1" id="if1" width="100%" height="254" style="visibility:hidden" src="http://www.google.co.uk">
        Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.
    </iframe></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This just forwards the query to Google, I'm talking about having the results show up in your layout.

Is it possible what I've seen is simply an iframe?

Comment: where exactly do I copy/paste the `<form></form>` in the html page? Must be another page?

Comment: @JustMe 13 years later, am I not so sure, but I would assume directly in the body of your HTML page. I have restored the first link: https://web.archive.org/web/20081231030633/http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_can_i_add_a_google_search_box_to_my_web_site.html. It does show you an example.

Comment: thanks, I find the answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822927/how-can-i-add-a-google-search-box-to-my-website/

Comment: @JustMe OK, thank you for the feedback. I have included your link in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 5):

For a free solution based on the main Google index using a `site:` query and only a little control of the look and feel, try [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/coop/cse/).

For a few hundred dollars, with a more comprehensive and up-to-date index of your site, and complete control of the look-and-feel, try [Google Site Search](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/).

For enterprises which need complete control of all aspects of the index and the search experience, and need anything from thousands to millions of items in the index, try the [Google Search Appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/gsa/).

Answer (score 3):

As another answerer listed, I beleieve Custom Search is what you are looking for.

Just wanted to provide additional info.  Google also has Site Search, but you need to pay for it.

Take a look at Google Webmaster tools:
http://www.google.com/webmasters/

In particular:
http://www.google.com/sitesearch/

Comment: thanks I think site search is actually what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to have a customized google search is to use adsense for search, it allows you to :

- Search in one or more sites, or the whole internet.
- Open in a new window, current window or iframe.
- Customize the colors of the search results.
- It could also pay you cents for any clicks on the ads.

Answer (score -1):

This same answer i have suggested earlier to another question so this is the answer

Go to this link https://www.google.com/cse/ and create account
Create your custom search box
Customize looks as your wish
Copy the code after customizing
Paste in your blog or website where you want the search box to appear..

And if you want search box like my site http://www.latestgames2.com/ just customized all the colors and shapes