# How can I add a Google search box to my website?

Tags: html, google-search

I am trying to add a Google search box to my own website. I would like it to search Google itself, not my site. There was some code I had that use to work, but no longer does:

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
<input type="text" name="g" size="31" value="">
</form>
```

When I try making a search, it just directs to the Google homepage. Well, actually it directs here: https://www.google.com/webhp

Does anyone have a different solution? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27):

Sorry for replying on an older question, but I would like to clarify the last question.

You use a "get" method for your form.
When the name of your input-field is "g", it will make a URL like this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?g=[value from input-field]
```

But when you search with google, you notice the following URL:

```
https://www.google.nl/search?q=google+search+bar
```

Google uses the "q" Querystring variable as it's search-query.
Therefor, renaming your field from "g" to "q" solved the problem.

Comment: can we have the search result at particular position or in a particular block

Answer (score 19):

This is one of the way to add google site search to websites:

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" class="searchform" method="get" name="searchform" target="_blank">
<input name="sitesearch" type="hidden" value="example.com">
<input autocomplete="on" class="form-control search" name="q" placeholder="Search in example.com" required="required"  type="text">
<button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. I'm making a start page for my local web server, so this will be great once I make it look pretty with CSS. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to Get the live Suggestions with this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, folks! for the NAME of the text box, you have to use "q". I had "g" just for my own personal preferences. But apparently it has to be "q".

Anyone know why?

Comment: Google expects a 'q' as GET parameter and uses the value to search the internet.

Comment: `q` stands for "query", which is a common term for searching a database.

Answer (score 1):

(The reason your code isn't working is because the GET request name is now "q" instead of "g".

I recommend using one of the two methods below:

Method 1: Simply send a GET request directly to Google (Best and most simple option)

```
<form method="GET" action="https://www.google.com/search">
    <input name="q" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Another (more complicated) answer would be

Method 2: Use JS to redirect to Google

```
<textarea id="searchterm"></textarea><button 
onclick="search()">Search</button>
<script>
function search() {
var Blah = document.getElementById("searchterm").value;
location.replace("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchterm + "");
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

From 13 March 2021. I make this very easy code for my website https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/how-can-i-integrate-google-search-box-to-my-website-by-implementing-custom-code.html

**First Step.** This is the search box. Copy this code where you want in your html/php pages. People will search here the information. This form will send the search results to another html page called `search.html`

```
    <form action="https://YOUR-WEBSITE.com/search.html" method="get" id="site-search">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- <label for="search">Search in website</label> -->
            <input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse">search</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**Second Step.** Create a new html page named `search.html`. And add this code in the `<head>` section, more likely before `</head>`:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'YOUR-NUMBER-CODE';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
```

YOUR-NUMBER-CODE you can get from this link  https://cse.google.com/cse/all (Here you must add your new search engine.. Also, put OFF on the option "Search the entire web" in order to find results only on your website, not the entire web)

**Step Three.** Copy this code in the `<body>` section on the same page:  `search.html`

```
<div class="main-content">
<h1>Search the site</h1><p>If you want to search for our articles on a specific topic, write the search term in the form below.</p>

<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
</div>
```

**THAT'S ALL.**