# How do large static sites make their content effectively searchable?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, static-site

One of the most popular tools  to generate static sites is [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) which is largely used in the Python community to document code. It converts `.rst` files into other formats like HTML, PDF and others. But how is it possible that a static documentation with plain HTML files is searchable without losing performance?

I guess, it's done by creating an index (like a JSON file for example) that will be loaded via AJAX and is interpreted by something like [lunr.js](http://lunrjs.com/).  Since many major projects in the world of Python have a huge documentation (like the Python docs itself). Therefore, how is it possible, to create such a good search without creating a gigantic index file that needs to be loaded?

Comment: There are many techniques that make indexing and searching efficient including tools like bloom filters and n-gram tokenization. Your question seems a bit too vague and open-ended for SO.

Comment: I've slightly added the post to make it more general. Your aspect has it's focus on natural language processing, but I'm searching a (combination of) tools that does this job already for me, rather than analyzing the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Search Engine](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/creatingcse) to use Google´s power on your site. It is difficult to customize yet powerful. Other reference in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822927/how-can-i-add-a-google-search-box-to-my-website)