# Why iframe or object are not support google / yahoo

Tags: php, html

Here i am using the code like

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com" style="width: 90%; height: 300px"></iframe>
<object data="https://www.yahoo.com" style="width: 90%; height: 300px"></object>
```

It showing the error like

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=TRAIWY7jO-KK8Qek6aOwDA&gws_rd=ssl does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

How can i fix it and show these url's in my iframe or object

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a ,  or

found:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

why not explore a solution like this:
[How can I add a Google search box to my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822927/how-can-i-add-a-google-search-box-to-my-website)

Look at this fiddle

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var url = iframe.src;
var getData = function (data) {
    if (data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.resources && data.query.results.resources.content && data.query.results.resources.status == 200) loadHTML(data.query.results.resources.content);
    else if (data && data.error && data.error.description) loadHTML(data.error.description);
    else loadHTML('Error: Cannot load ' + url);
};
var loadURL = function (src) {
    url = src;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20data.headers%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=getData';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};
var loadHTML = function (html) {
    iframe.src = 'about:blank';
    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html.replace(/<head>/i, '<head><base href="' + url + '"><scr' + 'ipt>document.addEventListener("click", function(e) { if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") { e.preventDefault(); parent.loadURL(e.target.href); } });</scr' + 'ipt>'));
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
}

loadURL(iframe.src);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2gou4yen/