# Integrate Google Search Box (not Custom Search Engine)

Tags: javascript, html, google-search

In a browser like Firefox or Chrome. When I open it up, it shows a homepage with Google search. The search box can show suggestion for every typing and when I press enter it does redirect to google.com with my search query.

I just want to integrate a search box like that. Is there any easy way to do it without building the suggestion myself?

**Someone said my question duplicated, however my question is different. I need a search box with full suggestion for every typing and I want to search all websites, not the content in my website as Custom Search Engine does.**

Comment: Have you googled it?  Read this doc https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4513903?hl=en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a Google search box to my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822927/how-can-i-add-a-google-search-box-to-my-website)

Comment: @mahan already googled, they all point to CSE (Custom Search Engine) which only allow you to search for a target website that you are the owner

Comment: @pujasinghal it does not have the search suggestion for every typing, which I want the most. And I want to search all websites, not search content only in my website

Answer (score 0):

You can embade google in an iframe.

```css
html,
body,
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1"></iframe>
```

Comment: It's too large, i just need the search box instead of the whole website.

Answer (score 0):

Without the suggestions it's simply:

```
 <form action="http://www.google.com/search">
   <input name="q"><input type="submit">
 </form>
```