# How to integrate google search engine to a chatbot using api.ai?

Tags: backend, google-search, google-search-api, dialogflow-es, google-search-platform

**The question is not about integrating on any website. It's about chatbots using AI**

There are inbuilt **domains** for web search, but those are **not free to use**.

So I was wondering if I can **query google search engine directly** and process it in the **backend code** and **return it as required**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275153/how-can-i-add-an-integrated-google-search-to-my-website

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can integrate Google Search, but you'll need to run a program (node/python) on a server that'll take the query parameters from the user and make the search and return a JSON.

Go to https://www.google.co.in/cse to make your own custom search engine. You can restrict search results from a specific website or not.